# cookies not being set for ionic 3 app in ios 13

Tags: cordova, ionic3, wkwebview, ios13

Ionic 3 app works perfect in ios 10,11 and 12. But after the upgrade to new version ios 13, the cookies are not being set in the wkwebview.
All the cross origin requests are hence failing.
CORS is enabled
If i degrade the webview to UIWebview, the crossorigin requests work fine.
But I can see some scrolling issues in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Degrading to uiwebview is quite a problem cause apple has deprecated its use.

Same issue here cookies are not set correctly. Requests seem to work.

EDIT1:
The main Problem is iOS13 Webkit view is killing the UseCredentials setting with setting no cookies. Best Practice use a cordova plugin from Oracle or work with api_keys.

Next Problem Apple is also Killing request Parameters from images..

Comment: What do you mean with "UseCredentials setting with setting no cookies"?

Is it possible that the use of localStorage is a credential too which we should not use anymore?

Comment: Webkit does kill any session you made cookie based even if you use UseCredentials: true in your request http header the result is even worser.

If you use the command UseCredentials and send requests with included api key the most backends drop the session. Current work Around is to handle the Sessions as a Token sending in the header or with an extra api_key parameter.

But this does not save you from the image and other content problems if the request there are behind an Auth